# Why am I getting parse error on input "{"

Tags: ghc, haskell-ffi

I am trying to run the very first example in this tutorial:

[Call JVM Methods from Haskell](https://www.tweag.io/blog/2017-09-15-inline-java-tutorial/)

```
module Main where

{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin=Language.Java.Inline.Plugin #-}
import Language.Java (withJVM)
import Language.Java.Inline

main :: IO ()
main = withJVM [] [java| { System.out.println("Hello Java!"); } |]
```

and I get this error:

```
app\Main.hs:8:26: error: parse error on input `{'
  |
8 | main = withJVM [] [java| { System.out.println("Hello Java!"); } |]
  |                          ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `{-# LANGUAGE ... #-}` and `{-# OPTIONS_GHC ... #-}` pragmas need to be defined *before* the `module Main` declaration.

Comment: Can you move this to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{-# LANGUAGE … #-}` and `{-# OPTIONS_GHC … #-}` pragmas need to be defined *before* the `module Main` declaration. Otherwise it will not enable the `QuasiQuotes` language extension, and thus not understand the quasiquotes used in the program.

If you install the [**`inline-java`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/inline-java) and put the language pragmas before the `module Main`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin=Language.Java.Inline.Plugin #-}

module Main where

import Language.Java (withJVM)
import Language.Java.Inline

main :: IO ()
main = withJVM [] [java| { System.out.println("Hello Java!"); } |]
```

It should normally interpret the quasiquotes properly.